# High current through Mosfet in boost converter?

Tags: ltspice, boost, step-up

I want to make a simple boost converter to step 5V up to anywhere from 30V to 65V
I want to be able to vary my duty cycle to be anywhere between there.

1. Did I chose a correct mosfet? I would like a mosfet in a really small package but I am not sure what to choose
2. How do I lower the current through M1 so I am not wasting unnecessary amounts of power
3. Should I opt for a BJT instead? See last picture

L is the 7447709102 WE-PD

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you want to know why the FET current is so much higher than the load current, zoom in on 3-6 cycles in the FET current waveform.

Comment: @ThePhoton I suppose I understand why, but generally I am doing this right then? Using the 2N2222A BJT as a switched seems to yield better power saving performance.

Comment: You haven't shared any simulation result that shows the power consumed by the MOSFET/BJT. You need to look more closely at the MOSFET drain waveform to see how much power is actually being consumed.

Comment: If you hold the alt key while hovering over a part in the schematic, you will see a thermometer. Left-click with the thermometer showing and the power consumption of the part will be plotted.

Comment: @ThePhoton I see that now. What current should I be expecting to see? is 300mA in the ballpark?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *How do I lower the current through M1 so I am not wasting unnecessary
> amounts of power*

You have chosen a diode that cannot handle the reverse voltage and that is then "swamping" both sets of results with nonsense numbers and waveforms. The 1N5817 has a peak repetitive reverse voltage of \$\color{red}{\text{20 volts}}\$ and it is **highly likely** that your simulation model **does** actually model this reverse breakdown voltage: -

[image]

So, when the MOSFET (or BJT) activates, one one side of the diode (cathode) is 55 volts (the output) and the anode is grounded so, you get a breakdown occurring in the diode and a ton of heat will be lost/wasted.

\$\color{red}{\text{Choose your components carefully.}}\$

This is what you should be getting with a 5 volt input, 55 volt output if the diode were ideal: -

[image]

You have calculated duty cycle correctly - some good news!

[**On-line simulator link**](http://www.stades.co.uk/Boost%20converter/Boost%20calculator.html).

Comment: Ah I see that now. Choosing a different diode seemed to help a lot!

Comment: You don’t need to worry about it being a Schottky either. With such a high output voltage, a diode drop of 0.3 volts or 0.7 volts is neither here nor there. Pick a fast diode though.

Comment: @Jirhska If you were using the 1N5817 model that's built into LTspice, then it doesn't model the reverse breakdown (no `BV` parameter defined).  However, that makes this answer even more important because it points out how even if you did get it to work how you want in simulation, then it will still be faulty when you build it in real life.

Comment: @SteKulov Interesting, the 1N5817 model I have has a BV of 20, consistent with the datasheet and consistent with why it didn't work

Comment: @Jirhska don’t worry about it. That was the problem.

Comment: @Jirhska It needs to be specifically `BV`.  `Vpk` is for informational purposes only and doesn't model anything.  See these images.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vebse.png  https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nw1eI.png

Comment: @Jirhska I'll leave you with one more screenshot and I'll shut up.  Don't need to believe what I say, you should run a DC sweep analysis on your own to get the I-V curves of diode models in question and see if they indeed do breakdown.  Here is my attempt at doing so with the two examples from my previous comment:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/GiEdB.png

Comment: @SteKulov Well I'll be darned.

Answer (score 3):

> Did I chose a correct mosfet? I would like a mosfet in a really small package but I am not sure what to choose

Nowadays, an SO-8 is a pretty big package (with pretty poor heat sinking capability).

If you want a small package, look for a DFN package. These can be 3x3 or 4x4 mm, although you'll have to do a careful search to find exactly what's available fitting your requirements for voltage and current.

> How do I lower the current through M1 so I am not wasting unnecessary amounts of power

The current through the MOSFET will be equal to the inductor current during the charging part of the cycle.

You can reduce the start up overshoot using a slow start circuit.

But you shouldn't worry that this wastes power. The power consumed by the MOSFET is equal to the current through its channel times the voltage across the channel. So if you pick a MOSFET with low \$R_{ds}(on)\$, and drive the gate sufficiently hard to put it fully in the on state (and to transition quickly between the on and off states), the power consumption can be kept quite low.

If you want to reduce the wasted power in this circuit and improve its efficiency, you should consider using a boost controller circuit able to drive a 2nd MOSFET as a "synchronous rectifier" in place of diode D1.

**simulation note**

If you zoom in on the MOSFET drain current waveform you will likely see something like this:

[image]

The current magnitude you in the zoomed out view comes from that initial peak each time the FET turns on, but the average current through the FET is much lower, in line with the load current as expected.

The turn on peaks  result from current through parasitic capacitance in the simulation model, and in the real world they will be dramatically reduced by interconnect inductance that isn't included in the model. You can also reduce them by including a resistor (say 5-20 ohms) between the switching voltage supply and the MOSFET gate.

Comment: So for simplicity I should just focus on getting Rds(on) lower? I added an edit with a BJT instead of a MOSFET too, the way I am driving it seemed to lower the current a tad

Comment: @Jirhska, if you compare the real performance between the BJT and a well-chosen MOSFET (not saying the one you picked is bad, but there are 1000's of choices and I don't have time to look at them all to answer this question) the MOSFET should come out more efficient.